# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'method' and 'float'

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

Every time I run it, I get a `TypeError` telling me that the operand is unsupported for Floats and Methods. I Could anyone give me an idea as to what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

```
from numpy import random,array,dot

class neural():
    def __init__(self):
        self.weights=2*random.random(3).reshape((3,1))-1
    def __sigmoid(self,x):
        return 1/(1+exp(-x))
    def predict(self,inputs):
        print("called predict function successfully")
        #pass inputs through our neural network (our single neuron)
        return dot(input,self.weights)

if __name__=="__main__":
    nn=neural()
    print(nn.weights)
    print(nn.predict(array([3,1,1])))
```

The exception including Traceback is:

```
     12     nn=neural()
     13     print(nn.weights)
---> 14     print(nn.predict(array([3,1,1])))



      8         print("called predict function successfully")
      9         #pass inputs through our neural network (our single neuron)
---> 10         return dot(input,self.weights)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'method' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
return dot(inputs, self.weights)
```

not:

```
return dot(input, self.weights)
```

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) is a built-in function while `inputs` is an argument for your function. Which should explain the exception.